# rdebug-ide with VSCODE returns cannot load such file -- /app/app/rails error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, ruby-debug

I have a dockerized RoR app and I'm trying to run it in debug mode using rdebug-ide and vscode.
Already added gems ruby-debug-ide and debase.
I installed ruby extension on vscode and created the launch config:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Attach to Docker",
        "type": "Ruby",
        "request": "attach",
        "remoteHost": "0.0.0.0",
        "remotePort": "9000",
        "remoteWorkspaceRoot": "/app",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "showDebuggerOutput": true,
    }
]
```

On docker-compose.override I added the command:

```
command: bundle exec rdebug-ide --debug --host 0.0.0.0 --port 9000 -- rails s --host 0.0.0.0 -p 3000
```

When I run `docker-compose up backend` I can see the debug server running:

```
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.7.2, debase 0.2.4.1, file filtering is supported) listens on 0.0.0.0:9000
```

The problem happens when I start the debug task on VSCODE. I get this error:

```
Uncaught exception: cannot load such file -- /app/rails
```

The entry point and workdir on Dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT ["bundle", "exec"]
CMD ["rails", "server", "--binding=0.0.0.0"]
```

If I run the app normally with `docker-compose up backend` and do `docker container ls` I can see the start command:

```
bundle exec rails server --binding=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: I have the same problem! But I haven't found a solution. Was there a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

In my case that was wrong path to `rails`, try to change it to `bin/rails` in `command`:

```
command: bundle exec rdebug-ide --debug --host 0.0.0.0 --port 9000 -- bin/rails s --host 0.0.0.0 -p 3000
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, do you have another solution @zooblin?

Comment: @MinhNguyen well there is multiple possible reasons, do you have all deps installed? what error do you see? I think it will be better for you to consider a new question

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution by myself.

Comment: @MinhNguyen if you found a solution, please post it

Comment: @Andrei: I used old rails version then binary path of rails is different, just update the path to binary rails. Hope this helps.